# Why are there 'conflicting overloads' for my kotlin class?

Tags: kotlin, oop, jvm

```
open class Result<T, E> private constructor(val ok: T?, val err: E?) {

    constructor(ok: T) : this(ok, null)
    constructor(err: E) : this(null, err)
    

}
```

I have here a kotlin class that is not dissimilar to Result in rust. I have a primary constructor, and understand that all of my other constructors need to delegate to it, but when I make 2 secondary constructors there are 'Conflicting overloads'. I think this might be an issue with the generics, because when I changed the type of one of the params on one of the secondary constructors to `String` then it was fine.

Comment: This is due to type erasure. During compilation, generic types are stripped away, so your constructors have the same signature. You can get around this by putting invoke operator functions in a companion object to simulate constructors. Mark them inline so you can use reified types. However, there’s already a fully featured Result class like this in the standard library, so you probably don’t need to recreate your own.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you should have posted this as an answer 

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I don’t post answers to questions that I think are duplicates. But I’m on my phone, where it’s hard to search for what it’s a duplicate of to suggest it.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04!